# npm install local does not create node_modules sub directory

Tags: npm, node-modules

I am missing `node_modules` after a local `npm install`, what went wrong?

```bash
Downloads % rm -rf DDD && mkdir DDD && cd DDD && npm install typescript            

up to date, audited 598 packages in 907ms
< ... rest omitted for brevity ... >

DDD % ls -l node_modules
ls: node_modules: No such file or directory # <--- what?
```

Comment: You piped the whole output into `/dev/null` without checking it? Maybe it contains some details? Also, what does your `DDD` folder contain instead?

Comment: I piped it just to avoid the `npm audit` message - it does not change when I remove the pipe - I will edit the question to remove it

Comment: my `DDD` folder is empty